# Android Apps crashes without explanation.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I am programming a tic-tac-toe android app, and I'm trying to use a for loop to make all the buttons in the array I put them in the same size.

However, when I put this line of code in to do that:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 9; count++){
    board[count].Height(ht);
}
```

The app crashes when I try to run it, without explanation.

What is going on?

Here is the entire code for reference:

```
package tictacstartns;

import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Button;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.Component;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.HandlesEventDispatching;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Form;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.HorizontalArrangement;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Label;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.events.EventDispatcher;



public class TicTacStartNS extends Form implements HandlesEventDispatching {

   private Button btnOne;
   private Button btnTwo;
   private Button btnThree;
   private Button btnFour;
   private Button btnFive;
   private Button btnSix;
   private Button btnSeven;
   private Button btnEight;
   private Button btnNine;

   private Button btnXOchanger;
   private Button btnReset;
   private Button btnClearScore;

   private Label lblTurn;
   private Label lblSpace;
   private Label lblXWins;
   private Label lblXWinsCount;
   private Label lblOWins;
   private Label lblOWinsCount;
   private Label lblCatsGame;
   private Label lblCatsGameCount;

   int ht = 75;
   int wd = 75;
   float fs = 50.0f;

   boolean xGoesNow = true;

   Button board[]=    {btnOne,btnTwo,btnThree,btnFour,btnFive,btnSix,btnSeven,btnEight,btnNine};


      void $define() {

      HorizontalArrangement hr = new HorizontalArrangement(this);
      btnOne = new Button(hr);
      btnTwo = new Button(hr);
      btnThree = new Button (hr);

      hr = new HorizontalArrangement(this);
      board[3] = new Button(hr);
      board[4] = new Button(hr);
      board[5] = new Button(hr);

      hr = new HorizontalArrangement(this);
      board[6] = new Button(hr);
      board[7] = new Button(hr);
      board[8] = new Button(hr);

      for (int count = 0; count < 9; count++){
       board[count].Height(ht);
      }

   EventDispatcher.registerEventForDelegation(this, "JavaBridge", "Click");
}


   @Override
   public boolean dispatchEvent(Component component, String id, String eventName,
                         Object[] args) {

   if (component.equals(btnOne) && eventName.equals("Click")) {
       btnOne.Text(xGoesNow?"X":"O");
       xGoesNow = (xGoesNow?false:true);
       return true;
   } else if (component.equals(btnTwo) && eventName.equals("Click")) {
       btnTwo.Text(xGoesNow?"X":"O");
       xGoesNow = (xGoesNow?false:true);
       return true;
   } else if (component.equals(btnThree) && eventName.equals("Click")) {
       btnThree.Text(xGoesNow?"X":"O");
       xGoesNow = (xGoesNow?false:true);
       return true;
   }
   return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh there is an explanation to it. Look at the stack trace of your logcat and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Button board[]=    {btnOne,btnTwo,btnThree,btnFour,btnFive,btnSix,btnSeven,btnEight,btnNine};
```

it contains all these references. But they are initialized to `null`.

When you do

`btnOne = new Button(hr);`

`board [0]` is **not** updated, so it stays `null`, causing an NPE when accessed.

This is because although references point to the same Object, when you reassign the value of one reference, it is specific **only** to that reference.

For a quick example:

```
String str = null;
String [] arr= {str};
str = "hello";
System.out.println ("The value of the reference is " + arr[0]);
```

The output is The value of the reference is `null`.

So make sure that the references you want to assign to the array point to an Object before actually assigning them, or do a double assignment, one for `btnOne` and one for `board[0]`. However, since you already have the array, `btnOne` is redundant.